# Broken/missing handler after reinstall

Tags: drupal

my site recently got deleted by a possible hack. I uploaded backed up folders and the db but now my views are not showing. everything else works.  i can't think of anything that changed, just uploaded a backup from a few days ago.

the fields are showing this in admin/build/views/edit/nameofview

```
Broken/missing handler: node_data_field_guru_photo > field_guru_photo_fid
Broken/missing handler: node > title
Broken/missing handler: views > nothing
Broken/missing handler: node_revisions > body
Broken/missing handler: node_data_field_guru_link > field_guru_link_url
```

I tried clearing cache

I rearanged the fields in views and updated them and got this error

```
Display "Defaults" uses fields but there are none defined for it or all are excluded.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally just clearing Drupal's cache would fix this but if not go into the 'Manage Fields' screen for the content type to which `node_data_field_guru_photo`, `node_data_field_guru_link` etc. are attached, make a temporary change (e.g. to the order of the fields) and save. That should force a refresh of the field cache and you should be on your way.

Comment: someone deleted views_handler_filter_boolean_operator.inc it was a hack :(

Comment: I had inactive fields (I think due to features issue), so using [cck_manage_inactive](https://www.drupal.org/project/cck_manage_inactive) helped.

Answer (score -1):

Just rearrange the order of you content type fields and then save it. In my case broken or missing handler was showing for Class content type. rearranging the content type fields solved my problem.